# Index not used when filtering with potentially null variables

Tags: sql-server, indexing, null

Please consider the following query:

```
Declare @ResourceId int, @AssetId int, @Start datetime, @Stop datetime

SELECT someFields FROM History
WHERE History.DateEvent BETWEEN @Start AND @Stop
AND (@ResourceId IS NULL OR History.ResourceId = @ResourceId)
AND (@AssetId IS NULL OR History.AssetId = @AssetId)
```

This query is only called with either a valid @ResourceId or a valid @AssetId, never both.

On `History` I have an index on `ResourceId + DateEvent` and another on `AssetId + DateEvent`.

Problem is even if @ResourceId is Null sql server will try to run what is after the OR and as a result, when I check the execution plan, neither of my indexes are used.

I try to replace the `OR` with:

```
AND ResourceId=coalesce(@ResourceId, ResourceId)
```

or even:

```
AND ResourceId=CASE WHEN @ResourceId IS NULL THEN ResourceId ELSE @ResourceId END
```

But to no avail. The only ways I can think so the proper index gets used are:

- build a query string with either `AND ResourceId=@ResourceId` or `AND AssetId=@AssetId` depending on which variable is null.

or

- Wrap `IF @ResourceId IS NULL BEGIN /* query 1 */ ELSE /* query 2 */ END`

Is there any other way SQL could use the right index depending on which variable is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

When you use function or case in your where condition, SQL Server don't use index. SQL Server must be run function or computed case statement and then check condition.

I suggest that create an index for ResourceId, AssetId and DateEvent columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thing is creating a third index would be very costly as this table is now approaching 100 millions records. Also I never have a query that run on both ResourceId and AssetId...